# Create a MySQL view to Get Average for Count Column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to create a view to get the sum of the count column and display the average as a new column. I used the below code.

```
select
    count(`t`.`surg_priority`) AS `Surgery_Count`,
    `t`.`surg_priority` AS `Surgery_Type`
from
    `DataBase`.`booking` t
group by
    `t`.`surg_priority
```

[image]

This was the result. I need a new column called average to get the total of surgery Avg.

```
Surgery Average = (Surgery Count / Sum of Surgery Count) * 100
```

I also tried

```
select
count(`t`.`surg_priority`) AS `Surgery_Count`,
`t`.`surg_priority` AS `Surgery_Type`,
(
    (count(`t`.`surg_priority`)/(sum(Surgery_Count))
    )* 100 AS `Surgery_AVG`  
from
    `DataBase`.`orbkn_booking` t
group by
    `t`.`surg_priority`
```

This too didn't work. Make sure this is a view. Cant use variable or cumulative functions

Comment: could you tried  `AVG`

Comment: @AntonyJack yeah I tried, That didn't support either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the total count in a subquery and divide the `Surgery_Count` by that:

```
select
    count(`t`.`surg_priority`) AS `Surgery_Count`,
    `t`.`surg_priority` AS `Surgery_Type`,
    100.0 * count(`t`.`surg_priority`) /
        (select count(`surg_priority`) from `DataBase`.`booking`) AS `Surgery_Avg`
from
    `DataBase`.`booking` t
group by
    `t`.`surg_priority
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select b.surg_priority as Surgery_Type, count(*) as surgery_count,
       count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from DataBase.booking b
group by b.surg_priority;
```

These have been available since MySQL 8+ was released.

Also, don't clutter your queries with backticks.  They just make queries harder to write and read.